# Which Greeks besides Cappadocian Karamanlis spoke native Turkish, who went to Greece after 1922/23?

Tags: greece, greek

I am interested in Greeks of Asia Minor, who were Turkish speaking but not Greek speaking, and who fled to Greece after the Turkish-Greek War; but before Lausanne Treaty. I am not looking for those who migrated after the population exchange treaty (such as most of the Karamanlis). (It can still be groups of Karamanlis, who fled during or right after the war).